# CoreBlutooth property is returning weird state

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm confused. I need to rely `canSendWriteWithoutResponse` in order to write to my remote peripheral using `.writeWithoutResponse`, but `canSendWriteWithoutResponse` seems to be false inside the block of when `peripheralIsReady` is getting called. How this can be the case?

Transcript What's new in CoreBluetooth WWDC 2017 Session

> For this year, we've enhanced CBPeripheral with a new property called
> canSendWriteWithoutResponse.
>
> So if you call this before you do a write and it and it returns yes,
> that's our promise to you that your data will not be dropped in
> software before we get a chance to send it to the remote peripheral.
>
> If that returns no, you'll also get a delegate callback when we're
> ready and we'll call back peripheralIsReady

It seems like `canSendWriteWithoutResponse` is false even though `peripheralIsReady` was called. How I can rely on this property if this is the case?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?